# Dialog box not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get a jquery dialog to appear (from some sample code) when a button is clicked but it wont for some reason. Hope you can help:

```
<html>      
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .html('This dialog will show every time!')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    title: 'Pick A Time Period:'
                });

            $('#reports').click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                return false;
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="reports">Hi</button>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Sorry guys, didn't realise that JQueryUI was a separate file. Only just learning JQuery today so it's all new to me

I've now added the correct script lines for the JQueryUI files and its still not working for some reason:

```
<html>      
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .html('This dialog will show every time!')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    title: 'Pick A Time Period:'
                });

            $('#reports').click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                return false;
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="reports">Hi</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, `<script>` tag should be closed with `</script>`. Next, where is your *jqueryui.js*?

Comment: As pointed out, you need [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). Otherwise, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/LTZpB/).

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

inlcude this lines between head tag just before jquery dialog script and see what you got!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```